# How to change clipboard (copy/paste menu) language to Turkish?

Tags: swift, localization, clipboard

i want to change clipboard language (copy / paste) to Turkish I created localization file in Project Info Settings like screenshot. Although my phone language is Turkish, but clipboard language is still English ?

[image: Project Setting Screenshot]

Btw what is the mean "0 file localized" ?

Comment: have you tried setting the locale property of the clipboard?

Comment: No. How can I set locale property ? Can you help me ?

Comment: I believe you nee to play with the UIPasteBoard, there you'll get the info of the items you want to paste. This is what I can do with this info, it is very little